# pip won't use install syntax

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have installed `python version 3.9.5` and `pip version 21.1.1`. Both of them I have checked in the Windows PowerShell using `python --version` and `pip --version`.

When I want to use pip to install an package using `pip install PackageName` the syntax just gives me a syntax error, saying that the syntax after the word pip is invalid.

What can I do against it like have I done any mistakes while istalling? I have already reinstalled Python unsing "Add to PATH".

Hadn't found any other forum with the same error yet. If there is any please feel free to show me.

Comment: Are you trying to use `pip` inside python? `pip` is meant to be used on the command line, not within python.

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip install PackageName`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: using `pip` directly like this is normally used for bash and/or a terminal with a virtual environment set up. Try setting one up and activating it, then using `pip install`

Comment: Also, could we see the error?